# Results are not loaded after rewriting url with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I have used `htaccess` file for rewriting URL

Earlier my URL was

http://example.com/New-York-Mills.php?ff_nm_from=new&search=hotel&location=north park

After rewriting with `htaccess`, it becomes:

http://example.com/New-York-Mills/new/hotel/north+park

But results are not displaying now. How can I get the results after rewriting url

Htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+New-York-Mills\.php\?ff_nm_from=([^&]+)&search=([^&\ ]+)&location=([^&\ ]+)

RewriteRule ^ /New-York-Mills/%1/%2/%3? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^New-York-Mills/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /New-York-Mills.php?
ff_nm_from=$1&search=$2&location=$3 [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /style.css [NC]
```

Comment: Give your .htaccess code

Comment: Please edit your question with htaccess code. It is nor readable in comment.

Comment: take a look here: http://bit.ly/1cVDaAM or like chanchal said, show us your htaccess

Answer (score 0):

how about it?

```
RewriteRule http://example.com/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/? http://example.com/$1.php?ff_nm_from=$2&search=$3&location=$4
```

hope it helps, otherwise show us your code

Comment: htaccess rules are not working in any browser except Firefox. Please help me to get them working on all browsers.

Comment: show your htacces code. htacces is dealed by apache, so it's not strict browser problem, but mayby you use some strange rewrite rules.

Comment: i've edited my post by adding /? at the end of http://example.com/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/? try if it works. also check if there's no other rewrite that would catch this action. i'll try to think what more could help

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this rewrite rule:

RewriteRule http://example.com/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/? http://example.com/$1.php?ff_nm_from=$2&search=$3&location=$4

but results are not showing and htaccess file not working in any browser except Firefox. Below is my htaccess code.

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+New-York-Mills.php\?ff_nm_from=([^&]+)&search=([^&\ ]+)&location=([^&\ ]+)

RewriteRule ^ /New-York-Mills/%1/%2/%3? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^New-York-Mills/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /New-York-Mills.php?ff_nm_from=$1&search=$2&location=$3 [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /style.css [NC]